# sed: replace a big block of code by another on a large number of files if the code block exists in the inspected files

Tags: sed, replace, zsh

I have the following block of code:

```
# Block bias spectro + pshot and correlations
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[0:7,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[0:7,0:7]
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[7:17,7:17] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[7:17,7:17]
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[0:7,7:17] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[0:7,7:17]
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[7:17,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[7:17,0:7]
# Block bias photo and correlations
FISH_super_flat_XC[0:7,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[0:7,0:7]
FISH_super_flat_XC[20:31,20:31] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[10:21,10:21]
FISH_super_flat_XC[0:7,20:31] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[0:7,10:21]
FISH_super_flat_XC[20:31,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[10:21,0:7]
# Block I.A and correlations
FISH_super_flat_XC[17:20,17:20] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[7:10,7:10]
FISH_super_flat_XC[0:7,17:20] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[0:7,7:10]
```

I would like to replace it, if it exists in files, in a large number of Python files by this new block:

```
# Block bias spectro + pshot and correlations
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[0:7,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[0:7,0:7]
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[7:17,7:17] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[7:17,7:17]
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[0:7,7:17] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[0:7,7:17]
FISH_super_flat_GCsp[7:17,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_GCsp_flat[7:17,0:7]
# Block bias photo and correlations
FISH_super_flat_XC[0:7,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[0:7,0:7]
FISH_super_flat_XC[17:31,17:31] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[7:21,7:21]
FISH_super_flat_XC[0:7,17:31] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[0:7,7:21]
FISH_super_flat_XC[17:31,0:7] = FISH_EUCLID_XC_flat[7:21,0:7]
```

I know that it may be possible by using `sed` (or surely `gsed` since I am on `zsh MacOS 11.3`) but I need help since I have only one shot possible (that's why I am going to make a backup of the director containing all the Python files to inspect).

I may use a command of kind:

`find directory_to_replace/ -type f -name '*.py' -exec sed **UNKNOWN COMMAND** {} \;`

I know to replace a word or regular expression with sed (like `sed -i 's/\(pattern1\)/pattern2/g` ) but I have no idea how to manage to replace big blocks of code like above.

Maybe I need to put these two blocks into text files and handle with `sed` the replacement but this is the first time that I need to do this kind of operation.

### Update

Given the solution done by `@potong`, I have put this command in a script and include the command in a loop over all Python files :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find . -type f -name '*.py'); do
echo $i
gsed -e '$p;e echo MATCH;cat matchFile;echo REPLACE;cat replaceFile' -e '$d' $i |\
gsed -Ez '':a;s/(.*)(.*\nMATCH\1REPLACE(.*))$/\3\2/;ta;s/MATCH\n.*//'
done
```

As you can see, I used GNU sed "`gsed`" since I am on `MacOS 11.6` :

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
./script_replacement_block_synthesis.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `.*'
./script_replacement_block_synthesis.sh: line 6: `gsed -Ez '':a;s/(.*)(.*\nMATCH\1REPLACE(.*))$/\3\2/;ta;s/MATCH\n.*//''
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does it _have to_ be `sed`? Use something else, for example, use `python`. `how to manage to replace big blocks` it's basically the same, just you have to read multiple lines, and then match multiline lines with the regex. It's hard with `sed`, simpler with `sed -z`. | `of Python files by this new block :` btw, wouldn't it be better to do a python function/library out of it, to ease future changes?

Comment: Editor's note: if [text is provided as images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179046/padding-left-issue-on-code-portions-of-a-html-page), and it is not repaired per requests, it can be closed & deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '$p;e echo MATCH;cat matchFile;echo REPLACE;cat replaceFile' -e '$d' file |
sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)(.*\nMATCH\1REPLACE(.*))$/\3\2/;ta;s/(.*)MATCH\n.*/\1/'
```

Place the contents of the match in `matchFile` and the replacement in `replaceFile`.

Append the match and replacement to the file in question and pipe the result through to another sed invocation.

Using pattern matching, match the matchFile with the match in the file and replace it by the replaceFile and repeat until failure.

Finally remove the match and replace files from the end of the original file.

Alternative:

```
cat file <(echo MATCH) matchFile <(echo REPLACE) replaceFile |
sed -zE ':a;s/(.*)(.*MATCH\1REPLACE(.*))$/\3\2/;ta;s/(.*)MATCH.*/\1/'
```

Or:

```
cat file <(echo MATCH) matchFile <(echo REPLACE) replaceFile |
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x;:a;s/(.*)(.*MATCH\1REPLACE(.*))$/\3\2/;ta;s/(.*)MATCH.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could you take a look at my **UPDATE** above where I mention the error that I get. Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 it appears the second sed invocation begins ``